# Get the exit code status of second to last command that was run

Tags: bash

say I have a set of commands like

```
touch /tmp/file.json
tool test --json |& tee /tmp/file.txt

firstchar=$(head -c 1 /tmp/file.txt)
ret=$?


#begin conditions.
if ((ret==0); then
##do something
```

instead of this:
`firstchar=$(head -c 1 /tmp/file.txt)`

The statement `$?` is checking for the last command run `firstchar` instead of `tool ...`

How can I make the conditional statement check the status of this command:
`tool test --json |& tee /tmp/file.txt`

Comment: `set -o pipefail` and move `ret=$?` to immediately after the `tool`